# merge a child changeset Y into an ancestor X

Tags: mercurial

Hi I have a change Y posterior to X, and I want to branch now from X and select only some changes that were made afterwards. In svn I'd do svn up -rX svn merge -cY. Any ideas if I can do this in mercurial without resorting to export or xplant?

Comment: The only way to do it that I found is to hg export -rY > /tmp/e ; hg import < /tmp/e

Answer (score 0):

The [transplant](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) extension may be what you're looking for. (Untested) I think it would be

```
hg update X
hg transplant Y
```